# Swift, how to use an array with indices to reorder another array

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing

In Swift I have an array of indices that I want to use to permute an array of values (very easy to do in Matlab), but can't figure out a simple way of doing it (using a for-loop would be easy, but I'm looking for a more efficient method).

For example:

```
var indices = [1,0,2]
var values = ["A","B","C"]
var permute = values[indices]
// Hoping to print: permute = ["B","A","C"]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var indices = [1,0,2]
var values = ["A","B","C"]
var permute = indices.map({values[$0]})
print(permute)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I even thought of using .map, just didn't know how to use it in the right way.

Comment: :) so glad this helped you!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution using `compactMap`,

```
let indices = [1, 0, 2]
var values = ["A", "B", "C"]
let permute = indices.compactMap({ values[$0] })
print(permute)
```

Comment: Why would you sue compactMap instead of map here? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: Just an alternative solution, anyways the question has hardcoded values as of now, later it might have nil values too.

Comment: Ok. I didn't see optional values that's why I didn't understand why you posted this. Maybe update your answer with this info? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just map the keys array to the values array.

```
var keys = [1,0,2]
var values = ["a","b","c"]
print(keys.map({values[$0]}))
```

Comment: As I stated, I'm trying to avoid a for-loop. I feel like there should be a function or shorthand way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
let indices = [1,0,2]
let values = ["A","B","C"]
var result: [String] = []

indices.forEach({ result.append(values[$0]) })
print(result) //["B", "A", "C"]
```